# How to get JqueryUI Sortable working with Zoom/Scale - mouse movements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get Jquery UI Sortable working with the zoom.  The issue is the mouse doesn't move with the same speed as the element you are dragging. There are quite a few examples posted about how to get this working with Draggable.  Here is a example of the workaround for Draggable items:

http://jsfiddle.net/TqUeS/660/

```
var zoom = $('#canvas').css('zoom');
var canvasHeight = $('#canvas').height();
var canvasWidth = $('#canvas').width();

$('.dragme').draggable({
drag: function(evt,ui)
{
    // zoom fix
    ui.position.top = Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom);
    ui.position.left = Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom);

    // don't let draggable to get outside of the canvas
    if (ui.position.left < 0) 
        ui.position.left = 0;
    if (ui.position.left + $(this).width() > canvasWidth)
        ui.position.left = canvasWidth - $(this).width();  
    if (ui.position.top < 0)
        ui.position.top = 0;
    if (ui.position.top + $(this).height() > canvasHeight)
        ui.position.top = canvasHeight - $(this).height();  

}                 
});
```

I would expect the Drag event to be replaced by the Sort event in the Sortable version of this, but as you can see from the below fiddle, it doesn't work. Setting ui.position in the sort event has no effect - it seems to set it and discard it after the event fires.

http://jsfiddle.net/TqUeS/658/

```
var zoom = $('#canvas').css('zoom');
var canvasHeight = $('#canvas').height();
var canvasWidth = $('#canvas').width();

$('#canvas').sortable({
    items: "div",
sort: function(evt,ui)
{
    // zoom fix
    ui.position.top = Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom);
    ui.position.left = Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom);

    // don't let draggable to get outside of the canvas
    if (ui.position.left < 0) 
        ui.position.left = 0;
    if (ui.position.left + $(this).width() > canvasWidth)
        ui.position.left = canvasWidth - $(this).width();  
    if (ui.position.top < 0)
        ui.position.top = 0;
    if (ui.position.top + $(this).height() > canvasHeight)
        ui.position.top = canvasHeight - $(this).height();  

}                 
});
```

If anyone has another workaround, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: When I test with the draggable, the item pushes toward each corner. Is this the expected activity? It seems to work well in sortable. Maybe I am not seeing the whole issue.

Comment: Testing here: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4nv60ob9/ if I replace `$("#canvas").css("zoom")` with `0.5`, I get actual values instead of `NaN` or `Infinity`.

Comment: It's reading it as a String with a value of "". Working on a fix.

Comment: @Twisty see here what I mean when I say that the mouse isn't in sync. http://i.imgur.com/up12PBO.gif

Answer (score 3):

Minor differences between draggable and sortable. In sort, the `ui.helper` is the item and `position` does not effect it in the same way, it's just a report of it's position.

For Draggable, in `drag` for `ui.position`, it states:

> Current CSS position of the helper as `{ top, left }` object. The values may be changed to modify where the element will be positioned. This is useful for custom containment, snapping, etc.

For Sortable, in `sort` for `ui.position`, it states:

> The current position of the helper represented as `{ top, left }`.

Try this:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4nv60ob9/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvas" data-zoom="0.5">
  <div class="dragme"></div>
  <div class="dragme"></div>
  <div class="dragme"></div>
</div>
<div id="report"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var zoom = $("#canvas").data("zoom");
console.log(typeof zoom, zoom.toString());
var canvasHeight = $('#canvas').height();
var canvasWidth = $('#canvas').width();

$('#canvas').sortable({
  items: "div",
  start: function(e, ui) {
    console.log("Sort Start Triggered");
  },
  sort: function(evt, ui) {
    console.log("Sort Triggered");
    // zoom fix
    ui.position.top = Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom);
    ui.position.left = Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom);
    $("#report").html("Top: " + ui.position.top + " Left: " + ui.position.left);

    // don't let draggable to get outside of the canvas
    if (ui.position.left < 0) {
      ui.helper.css("left", 0);
    }
    if (ui.position.left + ui.helper.width() > canvasWidth) {
      ui.helper.css("left", (canvasWidth - ui.helper.width()) + "px");
    }
    if (ui.position.top < 0) {
      ui.helper.css("top", 0);
    }
    if (ui.position.top + ui.helper.height() > canvasHeight) {
      ui.helper.css("top", (canvasHeight - ui.helper.height()) + "px");
    }
    $("#report").html("Top: " + (canvasHeight - ui.helper.height()) + " Left: " + (canvasWidth - ui.helper.width()));
  }
});
```

I think that is working in the same way.

Comment: It looks to me like it's doing the same thing - basically, the issue is that the mouse doesn't stay synced with the sortable item - it moves ahead of it typically. I see that you changed `ui.position` to `ui.helper` - in the jfiddle though, the mouse still moves away from the sortable item.

Comment: @user1274820 I am not sure I see what you mean.

Comment: @user1274820 this is much more complex than the small example you provided. Do you need items to only move along the Y Axis? If so, you may want to consider the `axis` option. I will do some more testing. Could you clarify your testing environment, Chrome? FireFox? Specific Version? Mobile?

Comment: Hey Twisty, note that I'm not the original poster - just someone who necro'd this. I have been testing on chrome. All that's really needed to make this work is to find a way to set the item position. With `drag`, it seems like `ui.position` works, but for some reason it doesn't work with in the `sort` function.

Comment: @user1274820 my apologizes. Not enough coffee. `ui.position` in `drag` does work to effect the position. `ui.position` in `sort` does not have the same ability. We can use css top and left, or `.position()` on `ui.helper`

Comment: I tried `ui.helper.position` with some of the code you posted and it didn't look like it was affecting the movement either.

Comment: I take it back - it looks like this is the code to fix it: `ui.helper.css("top", Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom));` `ui.helper.css("left", Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom));` - Possibly, when I change zoom to `.2`, it's broken again - still playing with it. At least I can change its position now though - that was the big issue.